# Hex timestamp to human readable in c

Tags: c, timestamp, hex

How do I get from a hex timestamp e.g. 33 88 72 52 to human readable?
I've pulled it from a file as an array byte = {0x33,0x88,0x72,0x52}, I think it is little endian...
Been a bit stuck on this for an hour or so and google hasnt been much help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends entirely on the encoding, which isn't specified.

However, at four bytes, it *could* be a `time_t` value which is supported by this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
    time_t tm = 0x52728833;       // little-endian 0x{33,88,72,52}
    printf ("%s\n", ctime (&tm));
    return 0;
}
```

This prints out:

```
Fri Nov  1 00:41:23 2013
```

which is only a few days ago (from when this question was asked).

So that's the most likely possibility (almost a dead certainty, I would venture) and you can use all the wondrous time manipulation and printing features of ISO C to work it out.